# как правильно добавить массив Jtextfield в Jlist(JScrollBar)

Tags: java, jtextfield

я имею массив

```
n= 30;//любое количество строк
 JTextField[] text = new JTextField[n];
         for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
             text[i] = new JTextField("",7);
             panel.add(text[i]);
         }
JList list = new JList(text);
         list.setLayoutOrientation(JList.VERTICAL);
```

теперь мне нужно запихать его в jlist, чтобы неважно до какого размера окно, пролистать до каждого элемента, как это сделать, сейчас выдает длинную хрень в Jlist'e?

Comment: 1) Добавьте ваш `JList` в  `JScrollPane` 2) Установите размер  `JScrollPane` 3) добавьте  `JScrollPane` на ваш `panel`(Сам `Jlist` добавлять не надо)

Comment: Или у вас проблемы с отображением текста?